# python shutil.copytree - ignore permissions

Tags: python, file, shutil

Python's `shutil.copytree` is not very flexible; what is the simplest way to add support for ignoring permissions while copying in `copytree` (without having to re-write its implementation)?

Otherwise, `copytree` fails like this:

```
(…)”[Errno 45] Operation not supported: ‘/path/foo/bar’”
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `shutil.py` in your standard Python distribution (on Ubuntu, mine is under `/usr/lib/python2.6` for instance; Windows might be `C:\Python26\lib`?).  The copytree function is only 38  lines long (34 if you don't count comments), and the end of the docstring explicitly states:

> `XXX Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool.`

So the simplest way really would be to change/add a couple lines to copytree, or find another library, to be honest.

Comment: That's what I did before posting this question.

Comment: source: [shutil.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/shutil.py#L549)

Answer (score 5):

Not thread-safe (or advisable in general) but OK for a throwaway script:

```
import shutil

_orig_copystat = shutil.copystat
shutil.copystat = lambda x, y: x

shutil.copytree(src, dst)

shutil.copystat = _orig_copystat
```

Comment: fix: `shutil.copystat = lambda *a, **k: None` because the original function signature is `copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.2 and higher, there's now a built-in way to do this. `shutil.copytree` accepts a custom file copy function as an argument. You can use that to change it from the default file copy function (`shutil.copy2`) to one that doesn't copy permissions like `shutil.copy`:

```py
shutil.copytree(src, dst, copy_function=shutil.copy)
```

Comment: This will only work for files since directory permissions are not copied with the copy_function. They are mirrored explicitly with shutil.copystat() instead.